# Why does Route::domain cause a 404 in Laravel on every route, including subdomains?

Tags: php, laravel

All my routes stopped working recently and I've narrowed it down to my `RouteServiceProvider.php` file. The reason is that I have `Route::domain` for the Web routes is for the main domain, while others are for specific subdomains.

If I don't have a `Route::domain` on the Web routes, it will make all subdomain routes act as if they were from the Web routes.

```php
public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            // Hub Routes
            Route::domain('hub.' . config('app.url'))->middleware('web')->name('hub.')->group(base_path('routes/hub.php'));

            // Dashboard Routes
            Route::domain('dashboard.' . config('app.url'))->middleware('web')->name('dashboard.')->group(base_path('routes/dashboard.php'));

            Route::middleware('api')
                ->prefix('api')
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::domain(config('app.url'))->middleware('web')->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
        });
    }
```

What is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: the reason why it was 404-ing was apparently due to `app.url` variable. Instead, I added a URL without http:// or https:// and it seems to be working.